how to fix Redirect failed error in BingImageCreator library
I want to use the BingImageCreator library
I use Bing to produce the photo, but I get this error
Of course, I must say that I ran this code several times and it outputted 3 times and I encountered this error many times
...\BingImageCreator.py", line 139,
in get_images
raise Exception(error_redirect)
Exception: Redirect failed
my code
import os

U_cookie_api_value =edge_cookie

def generate_image(prompt):

    command = f'python -m BingImageCreator --prompt "{prompt}" -U "{U_cookie_api_value}"'

    os.system(command)

    return os.listdir('OUTPUT')

p = 'any prompt'
image_list = generate_image(p)



can you share content of file BingImageCreator.py, or at least the relevant snippet ?

if response.status_code != 302:             # if rt4 fails, try rt3             url = f"{BING_URL}/images/create?q={url_encoded_prompt}&rt=3&FORM=GENCRE"             response = self.session.post(url, allow_redirects=False, timeout=200)             if response.status_code != 302:                 if self.debug_file:                     self.debug(f"ERROR: {error_redirect}")                 print(f"ERROR: {response.text}")                 raise Exception(error_redirect)
Library link:
pip install BingImageCreator
